# Invalidating WsFederation authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, ws-federation

I am using the OWIN WsFederation to authenticate users, I would like to grab a claim and perform an additional check to see if this unique user id is located in a database for access. If not I would like to redirect a user to a view that displays a message. I am subscribed to a notification "SecurityTokenValidated", in this notification I will grab the claim and check if the user exist. From my understand SecurityTokenValidated is called after the cookie has been created, so this may be too late.

How do I redirect the user to a view letting them know they don't have access?

```
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
    Wtrealm = AppSettings.IdpRealm,
    MetadataAddress = AppSettings.IdpMetadata,                 

    Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        // check and create additional claims
        SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
        {
            // identity object to access claims from IDP
            var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

            // get claim and check database


            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an exception to block the flow of the authentication. Something like this

```
throw new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException();
```

On the exception handler, add a friendly message to the user.